# How to customize expand and collapse icons of p:fieldset

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, icons, fieldset

How can I change expand and collapse icons of PrimeFaces 5.2 `<p:fieldset>` to my own icons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining the following styles worked for me:

```
.ui-fieldset .ui-fieldset-toggler.ui-icon-plusthick {
    background-image: url("#{resource['img/plus.png']}");
    background-position: left top;
}

.ui-fieldset .ui-fieldset-toggler.ui-icon-minusthick {
    background-image: url("#{resource['img/minus.png']}");
    background-position: left top;
}
```

This example assumes you have images named `plus.png` and `minus.png` in your `resources/img` folder.

Note that this actually overrides the default PrimeFaces styles and will most likely affect the whole application. If you need to change this on some form only, you will have to define a custom class to be placed in the `styleClass` attribute of your `p:fieldSet` and to modify the above listed styles accordingly.

So the "special" case could look similar to this:

```
<p:fieldset styleClass="my-custom-fieldset" ...
```

And the related styles would be re-defined like this:

```
.ui-fieldset.my-custom-fieldset .ui-fieldset-toggler.ui-icon-plusthick {...}
.ui-fieldset.my-custom-fieldset .ui-fieldset-toggler.ui-icon-minusthick {...}
```

Hope this will send you the right direction.

**UPDATE** - hover issue

As reported by OP, there may be issues in some browsers - the reason is that PrimeFaces adds class `ui-state-hover` to the `legend` node, which may not be processed correctly in some circumstances.

So you may either try to use simple selectors only - these should be applied always:

```
.ui-fieldset-toggler.ui-icon-plusthick {...}
.ui-fieldset-toggler.ui-icon-minusthick {...}
```

Or to keep the selectors more verbose, effectively specifying them twice - once for "normal" state and once for the "hover":

```
.ui-fieldset-legend .ui-fieldset-toggler.ui-icon-plusthick { /* plus */ }
.ui-fieldset-legend.ui-state-hover .ui-fieldset-toggler.ui-icon-plusthick { /* plus */}
.ui-fieldset-legend .ui-fieldset-toggler.ui-icon-minusthick { /* minus */ }
.ui-fieldset-legend.ui-state-hover .ui-fieldset-toggler.ui-icon-minusthick { /* minus */}
```

As explained in comments, I tested this in multiple browsers and could not reproduce the "hover" issue, so you may need to experiment on your own. All the above listed selector examples worked in my environment.

Comment: Hi Sva,Thanks for spending time on this.I am able to replace plusthick,minusthick with my own image with the code posted by you.But when I place mouse on the icon its displaying other image.Any idea on this

Comment: @vissu what browser are you using? I just tested and it works properly in Firefox (40.0.3). Chrome (45.0.2454.93) and IE (11 - tested all available compatbibility settings). Nevertheless, I just noticed style `ui-state-hover` is added when the mouse pointer is over the icon, so in your case the selectors might need to take that into account. I will update my answer to cover that as well.

Comment: Sva,the problem is with all the browsers.I identified the style class that is causing the problem with firebug.ui-fieldset-toggleable .ui-fieldset .ui-state-hover .ui-fieldset-legend .ui-icon is the styleclass used for this.But when i override this styleclass and set background:none; its not showing any effect.

Comment: @vissu have you tried forcing it? `background: none !important;` or `background-image: none !important;`

Comment: @vissu just to be suzre, did you include also the `!important` directive? If you did and it was not working, then I'm out of ideas for the moment. Maybe if you can post your code (the `p:fieldSet` with some context around it), it would help. Did you also try to clear browser cache, restart the server or rebuild/redeploy the app?

Comment: My mistake @sva.Its working fine with !important.Thank you

Comment: Glad it worked. Please mark your question as answered to make it easier to find for others with the same issue. Thanks!